# How to round a prediction when it should be a (non-categorical) integer?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Say I am trying to predict a variable y which is a score from 0 to 10 (integer numbers only), and I am using a linear regression model. The model actually produces *real* numbers in that interval.

I am using regression, and not classification, because I want to be able to say that missing the correct prediction by (say) 2 is worse than missing it by 1. Currently I am using the average absolute error as the evaluation metric.

Given the prediction from the model is a real number, what is the best way to constraint it to be in the allowed set of integers (from 0 to 10)? Should I just round the prediction to the nearest integer, or any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a multinomial logistic regression model and one can go for classification accuracy for the measure of the performance of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Have a range from 0 to 11, and round to the nearest .5 number. This gives you 10 evenly spaced, equally sized categories. If you can, weigh the regression on how close it was to the .5 mark, as the results should ideally not be close enough to the boundary to cause ambiguity.

Alternatively, have a range from -0.5 to 10.5 and use the integers as the target. It makes no difference but is compatible with your existing network.

Comment: Very insightful !